# Minitest class definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

In minitest_helper.rb I have seen the minitest class defined as:

```
MiniTest::Rails::Spec
```

or

```
MiniTest::Spec
```

What is the difference between these definitions?  I have also noticed where the basic class is set...such as

```
MiniTest::Spec::TYPES.last[1] = MiniTest::Rails::Spec
```

What does this accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

`MiniTest::Rails::Spec` is for testing rails sites, using the rspec-like dsl in minitest. `MiniTest::Spec` is just the plain rspec like minitest without the additional rails functionality.

The last line is adding rails matchers to standard MiniTest::Spec. There's a comment in the source explaining it: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/spec.rb#L97